# multicasting from c# to android using UDP

Tags: c#, android, udp, multicast

***I have developed UDP  multicast server in c# and UDP multicast reciever in Android,but iam not able to recieve data from server to client(Android).Is it because of the port numbers 
i have used in code ?  Your help is greatly appretiated and will save me nights.***

***Server code

```
namespace Server
{
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        UdpClient udpclient = new UdpClient();
        IPAddress multicastaddress = IPAddress.Parse("233.45.17.10");
        udpclient.JoinMulticastGroup(multicastaddress);
            IPEndPoint remoteep = new IPEndPoint(multicastaddress, 10000);
            Byte[] buffer = null;
            for (int i=1;i<30;i++)
            {
                buffer = Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(i.ToString());
                int flag = udpclient.Send(buffer, buffer.Length, remoteep);
            }
            MessageBox.Show("Data Sent TO " + ip.Text + "On Port " + port.Text);
            status.Text = "Connected";
        }
        private void disconnect_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
        this.Close();
        }
    }
}***
```

Client code(Android):

```
public class TestMulticast extends Activity
    {
        static boolean done = false;
        EditText et;
        TextView tv;
Button b;
MulticastSocket socket;
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    b=(Button)findViewById(R.id.b);
    et=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.et);
    tv =(TextView)findViewById(R.id.tv);

    b.setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener()
    {
        public void onClick(View v) 
        {
           try 
           {
              String msg = et.getText().toString();
              socket.send(new DatagramPacket(msg.getBytes(), 0, msg.getBytes().length, InetAddress.getByName("192.168.1.6"), 10000));
              Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "sent", 100).show();
           }
           catch (Exception e) 
           {
               e.printStackTrace();
               Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
           }
        }
});
if (!done) 
{
    try 
    {
        WifiManager wifiManager = (WifiManager)getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
        WifiInfo wifiinfo = wifiManager.getConnectionInfo();
        int intaddr = wifiinfo.getIpAddress();
        if (intaddr == 0)
        {
            tv.setText("Unable to get WIFI IP address");
        }
        else 
        {
            byte[] byteaddr = null;
            byteaddr = new byte[] {
                            (byte)(intaddr & 0xff), 
                    (byte)(intaddr >> 8 & 0xff),
                    (byte)(intaddr >> 16 & 0xff),
                    (byte)(intaddr >> 24 & 0xff)
                };
       String machineName = "androidtestdevice";
       InetAddress addr = InetAddress.getByAddress(machineName, byteaddr);
       tv.append("Using address: " + addr + "\n");
       Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "using address"+addr, 50).show();
      // create socket
      socket = new MulticastSocket(11111);
      // set network interface
      NetworkInterface iface = NetworkInterface.getByInetAddress(addr);
      Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "First address on interface is: " + getAddressFor(iface), 50).show();
      tv.append("First address on interface is: " + getAddressFor(iface) + "\n");
     // The following line throws an exception in Android (Address is not available)
     // If it's not called, the socket can receives packets
     // Equivalent code in seems to C work.
     //socket.setNetworkInterface(iface);
     // join group
     socket.joinGroup(InetAddress.getByName("233.45.17.10"));
     tv.append("It worked\n");
    // start receiving
    new DatagramListener(socket, tv).start();

  }
  }
 catch (Exception e) {
 tv.append(e.toString() + "\n");
 e.printStackTrace();
 }
 }
 }

class DatagramListener extends Thread {
    private DatagramSocket socket;
    private TextView tv;
    DatagramListener(DatagramSocket s, TextView tv) {
    socket = s;
    this.tv = tv;
    }
    public void run() {
    byte[] buf = new byte[1000];
    try {
    while (true) {
    DatagramPacket recv = new DatagramPacket(buf, buf.length);
    socket.receive(recv);

    System.out.println("received: " + new String(recv.getData(), recv.getOffset(), recv.getLength()));


    runOnUiThread(new MyRunnable(new String(recv.getData(), recv.getOffset(), recv.getLength()), tv));
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Now showing data", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "received: " + e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
    }
}
static private class MyRunnable implements Runnable {
    private TextView tv;
    private String text;
    public MyRunnable(String text, TextView tv) {
        this.tv = tv;
        this.text = text;
    }
    public void run() {
        tv.append(text + "\n");
    }
}
public static InetAddress getAddressFor(NetworkInterface iface) {
    Enumeration<InetAddress> theAddresses = iface.getInetAddresses();
    boolean found = false;
    InetAddress firstAddress = null;
    while ((theAddresses.hasMoreElements()) && (found != true)) {
        InetAddress theAddress = theAddresses.nextElement();
        if (theAddress instanceof Inet4Address) {
            firstAddress = theAddress;
            found = true;
        }
    }
    return firstAddress;
}
```

}

Comment: is this project working, I need to do something like this, thank you.

Answer (score -1):

Multicast packets are filtered in many android devices depending on vendor (some do others don't htc would filter it most likely), presumably to save battery. it is not blocked in android as such but the vendors.